# R GLM verifying performance statistics for validation

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I do not want to say my AUC is 0.77 and find out I am overlooking a lot. Below is my code and a two question at the bottom:

```
setwd("g:/docs/Model")
mydata <- read.csv("TModel_JUL16.csv")
summary(mydata)
mydata$ZIP <- factor(mydata$ZIP)
mydata$RACE <-factor(mydata$RACE)
mydata$GENDER <-factor(mydata$GENDER)
mydata$ADM_SOURCE <-factor(mydata$ADM_SOURCE)
mydata$TYPE <-factor(mydata$TYPE)
mydata$SVC <-factor(mydata$SVC)
mydata$WARD <-factor(mydata$WARD)
mydata$DISPO <- factor(mydata$DISPO)
mydata$STATUS <- factor(mydata$STATUS)
myglm <- glm(RA~ZIP+WARD+SVC+AGE+RACE+GENDER+ADM_SOURCE+TYPE+DISPO+STATUS+MEDICARE+LOS+IN+ED+PCI+CABG+DIALYSIS+AMI+CHF+PN+COPD+PVD+CVD+DEM+CPD+RhD+PUD+DIA+HePa+RD+SLVD+AIDS+DRUG+PHY+DEP+ALCH+PC+SYNC+SEP+ANEM+MALNEO+METCNCR+COAG+STK+NUTDEF,family=binomial,data=mydata)
summary(myglm)
prob <- predict(myglm, type="response")
mydata$prob=prob
library(pROC)
g <- roc(RA~prob,data=mydata)
plot(g)
```

These are my results:

```
Call:
glm(formula = RA ~ ZIP + WARD + SVC + AGE + RACE + GENDER + ADM_SOURCE + 
    TYPE + DISPO + STATUS + MEDICARE + LOS + IN + ED + PCI + 
    CABG + DIALYSIS + AMI + CHF + PN + COPD + PVD + CVD + DEM + 
    CPD + RhD + PUD + DIA + HePa + RD + SLVD + AIDS + DRUG + 
    PHY + DEP + ALCH + PC + SYNC + SEP + ANEM + MALNEO + METCNCR + 
    COAG + STK + NUTDEF, family = binomial, data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.1163  -0.5366  -0.4152  -0.1993   3.3030  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -1.689e+00  3.420e-01  -4.938 7.89e-07 ***
ZIP27546            -2.739e-01  3.302e-01  -0.830 0.406772    
ZIP28301            -2.902e-01  2.303e-01  -1.260 0.207606    
ZIP28302            -7.106e-01  3.673e-01  -1.934 0.053053 .  
ZIP28303            -2.099e-01  2.302e-01  -0.912 0.361849    
ZIP28304            -2.671e-01  2.296e-01  -1.164 0.244602    
ZIP28305            -2.592e-01  2.400e-01  -1.080 0.280171    
ZIP28306            -2.382e-01  2.292e-01  -1.040 0.298556    
ZIP28307            -3.045e-01  3.266e-01  -0.932 0.351269    
ZIP28309            -2.157e-01  3.672e-01  -0.587 0.556900    
ZIP28311            -3.222e-01  2.307e-01  -1.396 0.162574    
ZIP28312            -3.215e-01  2.318e-01  -1.387 0.165421    
ZIP28314            -3.420e-01  2.300e-01  -1.487 0.137042    
ZIP28318            -5.677e-01  2.739e-01  -2.073 0.038160 *  
ZIP28320            -4.234e-01  3.033e-01  -1.396 0.162745    
ZIP28323            -2.376e-01  3.488e-01  -0.681 0.495835    
ZIP28326            -4.029e-01  3.134e-01  -1.285 0.198625    
ZIP28328            -2.879e-01  2.830e-01  -1.017 0.309107    
ZIP28331            -3.942e-01  3.676e-01  -1.073 0.283493    
ZIP28334            -5.230e-01  3.004e-01  -1.741 0.081674 .  
ZIP28337            -7.301e-01  2.773e-01  -2.633 0.008465 ** 
ZIP28339            -7.499e-01  5.351e-01  -1.401 0.161082    
ZIP28344            -5.818e-01  3.578e-01  -1.626 0.103930    
ZIP28348            -2.847e-01  2.305e-01  -1.235 0.216773    
ZIP28356            -2.548e-01  2.606e-01  -0.978 0.328270    
ZIP28357            -4.823e-01  2.845e-01  -1.696 0.089980 .  
ZIP28358            -5.426e-01  3.033e-01  -1.789 0.073592 .  
ZIP28360            -7.954e-01  4.333e-01  -1.836 0.066423 .  
ZIP28371            -3.188e-01  2.474e-01  -1.289 0.197564    
ZIP28372            -8.082e-01  4.966e-01  -1.627 0.103637    
ZIP28376            -3.329e-01  2.355e-01  -1.414 0.157397    
ZIP28377            -5.883e-01  2.924e-01  -2.012 0.044251 *  
ZIP28382            -5.989e-01  2.901e-01  -2.065 0.038942 *  
ZIP28384            -3.009e-01  2.497e-01  -1.205 0.228286    
ZIP28385            -5.568e-01  3.771e-01  -1.476 0.139834    
ZIP28386            -3.303e-01  3.212e-01  -1.028 0.303847    
ZIP28390            -3.056e-01  2.364e-01  -1.293 0.196018    
ZIP28391            -2.482e-01  2.453e-01  -1.012 0.311606    
ZIP28392            -2.709e-01  3.952e-01  -0.686 0.493006    
ZIP28395            -4.320e-01  2.730e-01  -1.582 0.113550    
ZIP28399             1.235e-01  3.079e-01   0.401 0.688349    
ZIP28433            -6.764e-01  3.964e-01  -1.706 0.087937 .  
ZIP28441            -6.724e-01  3.890e-01  -1.729 0.083870 .  
ZIP99999            -6.239e-01  2.378e-01  -2.623 0.008709 ** 
WARD1YSU             1.606e-01  2.082e-01   0.772 0.440365    
WARD2SOU            -7.323e-02  2.365e+00  -0.031 0.975300    
WARD3SOU            -5.522e-04  2.365e+00   0.000 0.999814    
WARD3VPN            -4.266e-03  2.366e+00  -0.002 0.998561    
WARD3VPS             1.675e-03  2.366e+00   0.001 0.999435    
WARD4SOU            -1.826e-01  2.365e+00  -0.077 0.938458    
WARD4VPN            -9.387e-02  2.367e+00  -0.040 0.968371    
WARD4VPS            -1.046e-01  2.370e+00  -0.044 0.964807    
WARD5NOR            -1.089e+00  2.747e+00  -0.397 0.691615    
WARD5SOU            -2.720e-02  2.365e+00  -0.012 0.990821    
WARD6SOU             1.019e-01  2.365e+00   0.043 0.965635    
WARD7SOU            -1.450e-01  2.366e+00  -0.061 0.951123    
WARD8SOU             5.411e-02  2.365e+00   0.023 0.981749    
WARDAMUN             2.164e-01  2.389e+00   0.091 0.927827    
WARDAUNA            -8.279e-02  2.366e+00  -0.035 0.972087    
WARDAUNB            -2.720e-01  2.365e+00  -0.115 0.908445    
WARDCICU            -1.689e+00  2.397e+00  -0.705 0.481115    
WARDCPCU            -2.284e-01  2.365e+00  -0.097 0.923078    
WARDCSIC            -6.011e-01  2.380e+00  -0.253 0.800643    
WARDCSOH             1.874e+00  2.462e+00   0.761 0.446472    
WARDCVOU             1.647e+00  2.547e+00   0.647 0.517838    
WARDCVRU            -2.009e-01  2.590e+00  -0.078 0.938169    
WARDGATE             1.330e-01  2.370e+00   0.056 0.955249    
WARDLDRU             7.628e-01  2.371e+00   0.322 0.747704    
WARDMICU            -2.455e+00  2.412e+00  -1.018 0.308850    
WARDNEPH             1.173e-01  2.365e+00   0.050 0.960456    
WARDOBRR             3.546e+00  2.731e+00   1.298 0.194237    
WARDOBSB            -2.015e-01  2.367e+00  -0.085 0.932144    
WARDOBSC            -1.468e-02  2.368e+00  -0.006 0.995052    
WARDREBI            -1.046e+01  2.272e+02  -0.046 0.963262    
WARDRGEN            -9.732e+00  2.276e+02  -0.043 0.965887    
WARDSICU            -2.785e+00  2.421e+00  -1.150 0.249997    
SVCCAN              -1.211e+01  3.248e+02  -0.037 0.970243    
SVCCAR               7.815e-02  2.367e+00   0.033 0.973658    
SVCCTS               1.624e-01  2.368e+00   0.069 0.945298    
SVCDEN              -9.862e+00  2.292e+02  -0.043 0.965679    
SVCDET              -4.493e-01  1.940e-01  -2.316 0.020561 *  
SVCEBS              -1.049e+01  1.080e+02  -0.097 0.922647    
SVCEDC              -9.275e+00  1.762e+02  -0.053 0.958009    
SVCEGN               4.178e-01  2.623e+00   0.159 0.873433    
SVCEGS              -7.110e-01  2.605e+00  -0.273 0.784884    
SVCEMS               1.271e+00  2.674e+00   0.475 0.634671    
SVCENT              -1.088e+00  2.574e+00  -0.423 0.672522    
SVCERS              -1.021e+01  1.622e+02  -0.063 0.949780    
SVCEYS               5.866e-01  2.727e+00   0.215 0.829683    
SVCFAM               1.585e-01  2.365e+00   0.067 0.946573    
SVCGAS              -1.160e+00  2.472e+00  -0.469 0.638878    
SVCGYN              -1.024e-01  2.368e+00  -0.043 0.965523    
SVCHEM               1.286e+00  2.400e+00   0.536 0.592043    
SVCLDO              -1.005e+01  3.248e+02  -0.031 0.975306    
SVCMED               1.140e-01  2.365e+00   0.048 0.961554    
SVCNEP               2.326e-01  2.374e+00   0.098 0.921941    
SVCNEU               4.451e-02  2.402e+00   0.019 0.985213    
SVCNRS               1.361e-01  2.370e+00   0.057 0.954209    
SVCOBA              -9.934e+00  1.621e+02  -0.061 0.951132    
SVCOBD              -1.295e+00  2.370e+00  -0.546 0.584748    
SVCOBN               2.103e+00  2.368e+00   0.888 0.374650    
SVCOBS               6.057e-01  2.404e+00   0.252 0.801028    
SVCONC               9.306e-01  2.367e+00   0.393 0.694249    
SVCOPH              -9.914e+00  3.248e+02  -0.031 0.975646    
SVCORT              -4.223e-01  2.368e+00  -0.178 0.858437    
SVCPED               1.826e-01  2.751e+00   0.066 0.947061    
SVCPLS               1.412e+00  2.634e+00   0.536 0.591885    
SVCPOD              -1.153e-01  2.375e+00  -0.049 0.961262    
SVCPUL               5.282e-01  2.380e+00   0.222 0.824376    
SVCSUR               4.083e-02  2.366e+00   0.017 0.986228    
SVCURO              -4.731e-01  2.378e+00  -0.199 0.842283    
AGE                  8.543e-04  1.034e-03   0.827 0.408519    
RACEAMERICAN INDIAN  7.895e-02  9.533e-02   0.828 0.407607    
RACEASIAN           -1.006e-01  1.444e-01  -0.697 0.485921    
RACECAUCASIAN       -3.327e-02  2.774e-02  -1.200 0.230327    
RACEOTHER           -1.619e-01  6.037e-02  -2.681 0.007344 ** 
GENDERM              4.273e-02  2.687e-02   1.590 0.111745    
ADM_SOURCEOTHER      1.652e-01  4.486e-01   0.368 0.712637    
ADM_SOURCERA        -5.346e-02  4.963e-02  -1.077 0.281430    
TYPEJ               -3.104e-02  2.346e-01  -0.132 0.894746    
TYPEQ                4.522e-02  2.310e-01   0.196 0.844763    
DISPOHOME           -4.442e-01  3.863e-02 -11.499  < 2e-16 ***
DISPOHOSPICE        -8.949e-01  9.628e-02  -9.295  < 2e-16 ***
DISPOOTHER          -9.028e-01  5.873e-02 -15.370  < 2e-16 ***
DISPOSNF            -4.500e-02  4.718e-02  -0.954 0.340221    
STATUSMARRIED       -1.442e-01  3.970e-02  -3.631 0.000282 ***
STATUSOTHER          4.810e-02  6.469e-01   0.074 0.940723    
STATUSSEPERATED      4.294e-02  6.882e-02   0.624 0.532630    
STATUSSINGLE        -6.439e-02  4.105e-02  -1.568 0.116793    
STATUSWIDOWED       -8.910e-02  4.675e-02  -1.906 0.056670 .  
MEDICARE             1.305e-01  2.955e-02   4.417 1.00e-05 ***
LOS                  1.800e-02  1.815e-03   9.915  < 2e-16 ***
IN                   2.472e-01  1.237e-02  19.994  < 2e-16 ***
ED                   3.874e-02  5.256e-03   7.370 1.71e-13 ***
PCI                 -6.748e-03  6.773e-02  -0.100 0.920647    
CABG                -8.911e-02  1.604e-01  -0.555 0.578575    
DIALYSIS            -2.061e-01  1.090e-01  -1.891 0.058589 .  
AMI                  4.675e-02  6.219e-02   0.752 0.452175    
CHF                  1.293e-01  3.723e-02   3.473 0.000515 ***
PN                  -1.917e-02  4.010e-02  -0.478 0.632604    
COPD                 7.144e-02  5.151e-02   1.387 0.165506    
PVD                 -1.145e-02  7.589e-02  -0.151 0.880032    
CVD                 -3.169e-02  7.305e-02  -0.434 0.664416    
DEM                 -1.982e-01  1.141e-01  -1.737 0.082310 .  
CPD                  7.009e-02  4.825e-02   1.453 0.146283    
RhD                  1.712e-01  7.599e-02   2.253 0.024249 *  
PUD                 -4.804e-02  7.202e-02  -0.667 0.504767    
DIA                  1.380e-01  3.193e-02   4.321 1.55e-05 ***
HePa                 3.654e-02  1.240e-01   0.295 0.768183    
RD                   2.044e-01  8.159e-02   2.505 0.012246 *  
SLVD                 1.630e-03  5.426e-02   0.030 0.976036    
AIDS                 1.104e-02  1.582e-01   0.070 0.944372    
DRUG                 2.828e-01  4.687e-02   6.033 1.61e-09 ***
PHY                  1.747e-02  4.766e-02   0.366 0.714022    
DEP                  8.486e-02  3.800e-02   2.233 0.025548 *  
ALCH                 2.984e-02  1.049e-01   0.284 0.776109    
PC                  -8.581e-02  1.433e-01  -0.599 0.549288    
SYNC                -4.742e-02  8.126e-02  -0.584 0.559487    
SEP                 -5.585e-02  4.355e-02  -1.283 0.199657    
ANEM                 1.775e-01  3.449e-02   5.147 2.65e-07 ***
MALNEO               9.727e-02  6.513e-02   1.493 0.135309    
METCNCR              9.645e-02  9.398e-02   1.026 0.304741    
COAG                 1.308e-01  4.110e-02   3.184 0.001454 ** 
STK                  3.670e-02  8.925e-02   0.411 0.680945    
NUTDEF               4.451e-02  4.605e-02   0.967 0.333744    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 54757  on 67295  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 46202  on 67131  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46532

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 11
```

ROC:

```
Call:
roc.formula(formula = RA ~ prob, data = mydata)

Data: prob in 57805 controls (RA 0) < 9491 cases (RA 1).
Area under the curve: 0.7731
```

Using lrm I get:

```
 myglm <- lrm(RA~ZIP+WARD+SVC+AGE+RACE+GENDER+ADM_SOURCE+TYPE+DISPO+STATUS+MEDICARE+LOS+IN+ED+PCI+CABG+DIALYSIS+AMI+CHF+PN+COPD+PVD+CVD+DEM+CPD+RhD+PUD+DIA+HePa+RD+SLVD+AIDS+DRUG+PHY+DEP+ALCH+PC+SYNC+SEP+ANEM+MALNEO+METCNCR+COAG+STK+NUTDEF,x=TRUE,y=TRUE,data=mydata)
```

I get the following output:

```
                     Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                        Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs        67296    LR chi2    8554.47    R2       0.214    C       0.773    
 0         57805    d.f.           164    g        1.246    Dxy     0.546    
 1          9491    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       3.477    gamma   0.549    
max |deriv| 0.07                          gp       0.129    tau-a   0.132    
                                          Brier    0.103
```

when I try to run:

```
library(rms)
myglm <- lrm(RA~ZIP+WARD+SVC+AGE+RACE+GENDER+ADM_SOURCE+TYPE+DISPO+STATUS+MEDICARE+LOS+IN+ED+PCI+CABG+DIALYSIS+AMI+CHF+PN+COPD+PVD+CVD+DEM+CPD+RhD+PUD+DIA+HePa+RD+SLVD+AIDS+DRUG+PHY+DEP+ALCH+PC+SYNC+SEP+ANEM+MALNEO+METCNCR+COAG+STK+NUTDEF,x=TRUE,y=TRUE,data=mydata)
my.valid <-validate(myglm,method="boot",B=1000)
my.calib <-calibrate(myglm,method="boot",B=1000)
par(bg="white", las=1)
plot(my.calib, las=1)
```

I get a singular information matrix error on SVC. Is my only option to remove the SVC variable? I do not receive any such error when using glm.

Thanks!

Comment: You've put 165 variables in a single model! This is a recipe for certain disaster. AUC will hardly be the only worry you should have. 90% or more of your variables have insignificant effects for which you would have to do rounds of feature selection. Consider splitting your data and a possible use of PCA for dimensionality reduction.